# Exercise in Weibel's book Lie cohomology, Homology

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra

Can you please help me out to prove the following (rather easy (but not for me obviously)) exercise which I didn't manage to solve (Exercise 7.4.2, page 229)?

> Assume $\mathfrak{g}$ is the free $\mathbb{k}$-module on basis $\{ e_1, e_2,..., e_n \}$, made it into abelian Lie algebra. Show that $H_p(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{k}) = \bigwedge^k (\mathfrak{g})$, the $p^{th}$ exterior power of the $\mathbb{k}$-module $\mathfrak{g}$.

Thank you!

Comment: If you know that the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $\dots\to\Lambda^kg \to\Lambda^{k-1}g\to\dots$ computes the homology, this is trivial, since in the abelian case, boundary maps are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $a$ be a finite dimensional abelian Lie algebra, let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a basis for $a$ and let $U$ be its enveloping algebra. It is easy to see that $U$ is a polinomial ring with generators $x_1,\dots,x_n$. You can check that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a regular sequence in $U$, so using the result of Chapter 4 in the book that refer to th Koszul complex, you get a free resolution of the module $U/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, which is just th trivial module over $a$, as a let $U$-module. Use that resolution to compute $Ext_U(k,k)$, which is the Lie cohomology $H^*(a,k)$.

Comment: You accepted this faster than you could have checked that it worked...

Comment: I know, because in the meanwhile I checked what you said at the comment and what you wrote, coincides with what I thought. Thank you again.

Comment: The problem with those things is that being adequate and sure about them, needs experience and usually I'm afraid assuming on my own things without seeing them written beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $K$. The complex $(C_{\bullet},\partial)$ is given by $C_p(L,V)=\Lambda^pL\otimes_KV$, where $V$ is an $L$-module, and $\partial_p$ is a boundary operator. For the trivial module $V=K$ these space of $p$-chains is just $\Lambda^pL$, and since $L$ is abelian, the boundary map $\partial_p$ is zero, so that we have
$$
H_p(L,K)=\ker(\partial_p)/im (\partial_p)=\ker(\partial_p)=C_p(L,K)=\Lambda^pL.
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, why the complex is given in that form?

Comment: Has to do with the Chevalley- Eilenberg complex if I understand correctly? But doens't assume at the point that the above exercise is given this kind of knowledge unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it is the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex. When does Weibel introduce it?

Comment: A couple of sections afterwards I think.

Comment: The enveloping algebra of an abelian algebra is just a polynomial ring, and in that case you have the Koszul complex as a resolution. It does coincide with the Chevalley-Eilenberg resolution but you do not need that.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that's helpful I think, but if you have a couple of minutes can you post this as answer a bit more detailed please? It would be helped me out a lot to see it written roughly.